# Storing bernoulli number is giving overflow error in python even after using decimal module

Tags: python, integer, decimal, integer-overflow, bernoulli-numbers

I'm trying to store first 1000 bernoulli numbers in a dictionary in python. At first I just stored the numbers as it is. So I got an overflow error. Now after going through previous answers I thought of using decimal module.

So here it is

```
-5218507479961513801890596392421261361036935624312258325065379143295948300812040703848766095836974598734762472300638625802884257082786883956679824964010841565051175167717451747328911935282639583972372470105587187736495055501208701522099921363239317373617854217050435670713936357978555246779460902210809009009539232173 / 2291190
```

The 260th bernouli number. I was able to store all the previous ones in the dictionary.

This is the sample code I've written.

```
from decimal import *
d = Decimal
getcontext().prec = 10000
di = {260: d(-5218507479961513801890596392421261361036935624312258325065379143295948300812040703848766095836974598734762472300638625802884257082786883956679824964010841565051175167717451747328911935282639583972372470105587187736495055501208701522099921363239317373617854217050435670713936357978555246779460902210809009009539232173 / 2291190)}
```

This is the error snap shot

[image: Error image]

Is there any better way to handle such huge numbers ? Please tell me if there is some thing that can be done to store these numbers.

Comment: You aren't using the `decimal` module properly. You need to convert your terms to Decimal _before_ you do arithmetic on them. As an alternative, you can use the `fractions` module, and store your Bernoulli numbers as rational numbers

Comment: Ohh.. okay so actually what I have done is I used matlab to generate all these numbers. Matlab generates only in the fraction format. So I have to do like that

Comment: BTW, you can't get integer overflow in Python, since Python integers grow as required. You're getting _float_ overflow, as that error message states.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for suggesting me the fractions module. I would use that

Comment: The `decimal` module is ok for simple arbitrary precision arithmetic, but it only provides the 4 basic arithmetic functions, plus square roots. If you need more advanced functions, please take a look at the 3rd-party `mpmath` module: it has built-in [Bernoulli number](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/numtheory.html?bernoulli-numbers-and-polynomials#bernoulli-numbers-and-polynomials) functions.

Comment: Ohh thanks man but the thing is I'm using these bernoulli numbers to solve a problem in hackerrank which doesn't support mpmath. So I have to rely on this

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the large number to `Decimal` before doing the division, i.e.:

(Note the end of brackets)

```
di = {260: d(-5218507479961513801890596392421261361036935624312258325065379143295948300812040703848766095836974598734762472300638625802884257082786883956679824964010841565051175167717451747328911935282639583972372470105587187736495055501208701522099921363239317373617854217050435670713936357978555246779460902210809009009539232173) / 2291190}
```